# How to Make Compare Json Data method in flutter/dart

Tags: json, dart, flutter

I have data and i want to create method to compare this data with JSON data from an API anyone know how to do this ?

Answer (score 1):

Someone from google seems to have had a shot at it, maybe try: 
https://github.com/google/dart-json_diff

Comment: As it is, this is a link-only answer. Please consider adding the most important information from the linked reference.

Answer (score 1):

Hope my answer helps you .. upvote if you like

Below is the method you can use for comparing the two json in dart

```
    bool compareJson(dynamic json1, dynamic json2) {
  // Check if the types of the objects are the same
  if (json1.runtimeType != json2.runtimeType) {
    return false;
  }

  // Compare dictionaries
  if (json1 is Map<String, dynamic> && json2 is Map<String, dynamic>) {
    // Check if both dictionaries have the same keys
    if (!json1.keys.toSet().containsAll(json2.keys.toSet()) ||
        !json2.keys.toSet().containsAll(json1.keys.toSet())) {
      return false;
    }

    // Recursively compare the values for each key
    for (var key in json1.keys) {
      if (!compareJson(json1[key], json2[key])) {
        return false;
      }
    }
    return true;
  }

  // Compare lists
  if (json1 is List<dynamic> && json2 is List<dynamic>) {
    // Check if both lists have the same length
    if (json1.length != json2.length) {
      return false;
    }

    // Recursively compare the values at each index
    for (var i = 0; i < json1.length; i++) {
      if (!compareJson(json1[i], json2[i])) {
        return false;
      }
    }
    return true;
  }

  // Compare other types of values
  return json1 == json2;
}
```

example

```
    void main() {
      // Example JSON objects
      var json1 = {
        "name": "John",
        "address": {
          "street": "123 Main St",
          "city": "New York"
        },
        "age": 30,
      };
    
      var json2 = {
        "name": "John",
        "age": 30,
        "address": {
          "street": "123 Main St",
          "city": "New York"
        }
      };
    // Compare the JSON objects
      var result = compareJson(json1, json2);
      // Check the result
      if (result) {
        print("The JSON objects are identical.");
      } else {
        print("The JSON objects are not identical.");
      }
}
```